# not reading lines from socket peer

Tags: java, sockets

EDIT: A poorly researched question, written when I was in a rush-it has nothing to do with socket.accept()-see below for accepted answer.Please no more downvoting.

I'm new to socket programming and in my toy 'Server' class I'm not getting any lines from the peer:

```
public class Server {
private ServerSocket myServerSocket;
String messageFromClient=null;
private void startServer(){
    try{
    myServerSocket=new ServerSocket(2000);
     int portUsed= myServerSocket.getLocalPort();
     System.out.println(portUsed);
    Socket mySocket=myServerSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("accepted");
    InputStreamReader streamFromClient =  new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader streamReader= new BufferedReader(streamFromClient);
    messageFromClient=streamReader.readLine();
    System.out.println("current message:"+messageFromClient);
    if(messageFromClient!=null){
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
        ps.print("Thank you client, I gratefully received from your message-hi from server!");
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

for completeness, here is the client class:

```
 public class Client {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private void startClient(){
    try{
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2000);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ps.print("hi from client");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    System.out.println("From Server:"+reader.readLine());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

They both have main methods. Any help would be very much appreciated thanks you!

Comment: Is there any exception being printed out?

Comment: Are you starting the client while the server is running?

Comment: If you think it's an exception, there should be a stack trace from the `catch`. If it's just hanging on the `accept`, then probably you haven't ran the client.

Comment: First run server and then client.

Comment: 1. Check whether your server is running on that port or not. You can check netstat -n command. 2) If the server is running on a particular port, check your client has access to connect to it. e.g. telnet ip port 3) In your client class, after creating socket, add one more System.out.println("connected");

Comment: What do you mean 'I have a feeling'? Don't you know? Did you look? What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `println` instead of all `print`s. As an explanation, while your server is waiting for an end of line character your client never sends. And it is same for when your server sends a message.

Comment: @EShindler If this answer is correct your title and entire question are wrong. You *did* get beyond `accept()`.

Comment: I made a mistake-when running in debug I believe I only ran the server in error. Sorry-mistakes happen

Comment: @EShindler All in all a very sloppily researched and asked question.

Comment: Points taken-I was in a rush and it's not the best question I've ever asked. Please, no more downvoting though.